# In SpringMVC I want create Hello World with Http Session

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

First of all, my English is not good, so I will use the image, hope everyone sympathize
I follow step by step in the tutorial video, but when running it does not work, I do not understand why, expect people to help

1. web.xml

[xml file](http://www.upsieutoc.com/image/4sxqtC)

2: HomeController

```
@Controller
  public class OfferController {
@RequestMapping ( "/" )
public String home ( HttpSession session ) {
  session.setAttribute ( "name" , "hello world" );
return "index";
```

}

3 : dispatcher-servlet

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.controller"/>
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <bean 
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
  id="viewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/web/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>
```

4: index.jsp

```
Session: <%=  session.getAttribute("name") %>
```

Comment: sorry, i will fix

Comment: What isn't working? No stacktrace, no error message... Currently the question is considered off topic with the reason *why doesn't this code work*.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Responsebody annotation on the home() and try

Comment: That won't help as that will return `index` as the result instead of resolving to a view named `index`.

Answer (score 0):

use sessionScope.getAttribute("name")